# Cannot include php files from root using subdomain

Tags: php, include-path

I have recently made an API now for that api i have made a subdomain however it broke my php file includes

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/init.php';
```

now my subdomain i am using is api.website.com and i need to include something from website.com when i try to include its giving the root of the subdomain,

Summary 
When i try to include init.php i get

```
Warning: include(/home/website/public_html/API/core/init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/api/apex/getusers.php on line 2
```

When i actually need

```
Warning: include(/home/website/public_html/core/init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/api/apex/getusers.php on line 2
```

I apologize for my grammar if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your include path to

```
include ("../../core/init.php");
```

will fix your problem.   However, this is not a recommended approach.

You should think about using a dependency manager like composer.  ( https://getcomposer.org/ ).  Then your included files will always be under a directory like

```
/home/website/public_html/vendor/core
```

and there will be less of a chance of your application breaking if the files in /home/website/public_html/core change.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
    include("../core/init.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  '/../core/init.php';
```

visit https://developer.hyvor.com/php/including-files-in-root-with-subdomain.php to learn more.